# Managed client implementing interfaces defined in managed COM object

Tags: com

I'd like to have a managed com object that exposes methods which accept as arguments objects implementing given interfaces. Something like this

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(".....")]
class SomeClass {

public void SomeMethod(ISomeInterface arg)
.....
```

Apparently `ISomeInterface` should also be declared `ComVisible`.

Now I want to consume that COM object in a managed client and call `SomeMethod` there. The problem is I need to instantiate an object that implements `ISomeInterface`. If that was a native COM object I'd get an interop assembly generated automatically and that won't be a problem. One cannot generate an interop assembly for managed COM object though.

I see that .NET 4.0 introduces the type equivalence concept. It looks like I could generate an interop manually using the `ComImport` attribute. But that looks like a pretty nasty job. I guess I could also use the `TypeIdentifierAttribute` but the documentation on that is vague and it says it's mostly intended for use by compilers.

So are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: This is backwards.  It makes no sense to have managed code use COM interop, it should simply add a reference to the assembly and use the class directly.  Native code that uses this [ComVisible] class should use the type library that you create with Tlbexp.exe or the Regasm.exe /tlb option so it can use the proper definition of ISomeInterface.  Type equivalence is nice to avoid a PIA, not an issue here.

Comment: Well I have a pretty complex deployment scenario that involves a number of assemblies being merged to a single assembly. So adding a reference to the original assembly is not really trivial. Also, The chances are my managed COM object gets instantiated by a client using earlier version of the .NET framework. So direct reference is not going to work.

Comment: None of these are reasons that would prevent adding a reference.

Comment: So I can have a .NET 3.5 assembly that refers .NET 4.0 assembly?